# Write a Mongoose method that updates/saves?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

In my order documents, I have a current `status` property:

```
const StatusSchema = new Schema({
  code: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    enum: ['pending', 'paid', 'failed'],
  },
  updatedAt: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
    default: Date.now,
  },
})
```

I also keep track of *past* statuses in an array. So, within my actual `Order` schema, I have something like:

```
status: {
  type: StatusSchema,
},
statusHistory: [
  StatusSchema,
],
```

Now, when I change an order's `status.code`, I want the previous status to get pushed into `statusHistory`, without having to manually do that every time.

My understanding is that a method would be the most appropriate way to do this. So I've written:

```
OrderSchema.methods.changeStatus = async function (status) {
  const order = await this.model('Order').findById(this.id)
  order.statusHistory.push(this.status)
  order.status = {
    code: status,
  }
  return order.save()
}
```

This does seem to work. However, when I use it like:

```
const order = await Order.findById(id) // Has status "pending" here
await order.changeStatus('failed')
console.log(order.status) // Still pending, reference not updated
```

My original `order` variable here does not update - the console log will print the original order fetched via the `findById` query, despite the fact that the document has been successfully updated and saved.

**How can I write a Mongoose method that will update a variable in place, without having to reassign things?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `changeStatus` method, you already have the `Order` document it was called from available as `this`, so you should update that rather than calling `findById` so that the changes are reflected in the calling doc.

```
OrderSchema.methods.changeStatus = function (status) {
  const order = this
  order.statusHistory.push(this.status)
  order.status = {
    code: status,
  }
  return order.save()
}
```

Comment: Okay, I had a feeling this might be the answer. There should really be examples like this in the official docs. Thanks.